# How can I validate Filter Builder expression from dev extreme in React?

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I'm using the FilterBuilder component from **DevExtreme** and I can't find a way to validate its expression.
I know that you can use the `IsFilterExpressionValid` method in javascript to validate it.
Is there a similar method to React?